# tcp connection last activity or open timestamp

Tags: networking

Is there a way to get an open tcp connections latest activity timestamp or first open timestamp?

I am trying to recycle some tcp connections and I would like to do it fairly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [iptables](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man8/iptables.8.php) along with either [LOG](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97702/log-network-activity-in-ubuntu-server) and ULOG target.

These targets turn on kernel logging of matching packets.